# intersects doesn't always work ursina engine

Tags: python, ursina

I have a bullet class and sometimes when it have to hit something it doesn't hit it(intersects function doesn't senses when it hits a thing(in my case the zombie) so it pierces through it and i don't know why.
Please help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the collider was too small so i make it bigger and it worked

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: this is my answer the collider was too small for the zombie and i make it bigger and now its working what's the problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

For bullets I recommend using raycast instead, unless the bullet is big and moves slowly. Otherwise what will often happen is that the bullet moves too far in a frame and can miss the intersection.

Comment: its still the same sometimes it works sometimes not